# Ebay File Exchange Custom Field Removal or Rename

Tags: ebay-api

I have some custom fields on my Ebay listings that I want to remove or rename. Is there a way to do this via file exchange or even the API if need be? Or are the listings going to need to be reuploaded or edited manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## File Exchange

In order to do any sort of modification to the "Item Specifics" section of a listing via File Exchange you must do a **Revise** request followed by **ALL** of your custom Item Specific Name/Value pairs. You are not able to do any sort of "cherry picking" of what you would like to modify. It's all or nothing.

#### Example

[image]

If say we wanted to to change the "Brand" value from "SanDisk" to "Apple" we would need to have a file resembling this.
[image]

This will update the brand correctly while still retaining the existing Item Specifics where if something like say this was sent[image]

All existing custom Item Specifics would be removed and the listing would then only have "Storage Capacity" as an Item Specific